# problem about ros-indigo-ros for armrf

Tags: ros-indigo, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I tried the Raspberry PI 3 the following installation TurtleBot, enter the command: sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros,But failed. I can not install it.
I found the ros-indigo-ros_1.11.13-0trusty-20160627-162641-0700_amd64.deb,But it is only applies to X86.How can I use it in armrf such as Raspberry PI 3? thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242534/problem-about-ros-indigo-ros-for-armrf/) by [Steven.Zhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/27851/steven.zhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't heard of any users installing ROS Indigo on the Raspberry Pi 3.

You don't say which OS you're using, or which installation instructions you're following, so I can't you debug your specific issue.

I've heard that most users have success installing Ubuntu 16.04 on their Pi 3, and then install the armhf packages for Kinetic. The [Kinetic install on Ubuntu page](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) clearly lists support for armhf on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven.Zhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/27851/steven.zhang/) on 2016-08-27**:
The Kinetic have a lot of packages do not support now,so I used the indigo.The OS is Raspbian Jessie,I try to install Turtlebot,install ros-indigo-ros and catkin_make rocon,it is failed.But ROS indigo on Raspberry Pi 3 is success.I can run roscore in Raspberry Pi.